# IF statement not working inside Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have a column in my database stored as JSON:

`{"all_catalogue":0,"5":"all","15":["40","32","50"]}`

I am using Casts in my model so this JSON get converted to an array automatically:

```
array:3 [▼
  "all_catalogue" => 0
  5 => "all"
  15 => array:3 [▶]
]
```

For some reason that is driving me crazy the if statement in the below loop does not work:

```
$int = $this->interests;
foreach($int->categories as $ind => $i) {
  if($i == "all") {
    $var = 1;
  }
}
return $var
```

This give me an error that `$var` does not exist. Can someone save me?

I am adding the full code below:

(according to my array above I should have 2 arrays inside the $more)

```
public function getInterestAttribute() {
        $int = $this->interests;
        foreach($int->categories as $ind => $i) {
            /**
             * If all catalogue we break the foreach
             */
            if($ind == 'all_catalogue' && $i == 1) {
                $interest = \App\Categories::where('category_parent_id','!=',0)->get(['category_id']);
                break;
            }
            if($i == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if($i == "all") {
                $more[] = \App\Categories::where('category_parent_id',$ind)->get(['category_id']);
            } else {
                $more[] = \App\Categories::whereIn('category_id',$i)->get(['category_id']);
            }
        }
        return $more;
    }
```

this only return

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Collection {#961 ▼
    #items: array:3 [▶]
  }
]
```

If I remove the `if ($i == 0)` then I got 3 array in $more... seems like is considering `$i == 0` for some reason

Comment: if the array doesn't contain a cell contain "all" , what should you return in your var ?

Comment: Please can you add all the code for the model so that we can see the code snippet in context :)

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI I have added the full code

Comment: @Rwd I have added the full code

Comment: if i really understand , the first loop will execute the code of the second **if statement**  . and then , the second loop will enter in the third **if statement** , and finnaly for the last loop , it will execute the last else in the loop . may be your sql request did not found anything that way you have only one element

Comment: when you  remove the if ($i == 0) response is correct ??

Comment: @Hamelraj no, as I said in the bottom if I remove the ($i == 0) then I got 3 arrays

Comment: Why even use a `foreach` here? You know the keys of your array

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$int = $this->interests;
foreach($int->categories as $ind => $i) {
  if($i == "all") {
    $var = 1;
  }
}
return $var
```

with

```
$int = $this->interests;
$var='default value';
foreach($int->categories as $ind => $i) {
  if($i == "all") {
    $var = 1;
  }
}
return $var
```

Comment: the problem is that I should get the $var because the IF is true

Answer (score 0):

Well I sort it out by checking if $i is an array instead of checking it as string:

```
public function getInterestAttribute() {
        $int = $this->interests;
        foreach($int->categories as $ind => $i) {
            /**
             * If all catalogue we break the foreach
             */
            $iv[] = $i;
            if($ind == 'all_catalogue' && $i == 1) {
                $interest = \App\Categories::where('category_parent_id','!=',0)->get(['category_id']);
                break;
            }
            if($ind == 'all_catalogue' && $i == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if(is_array($i)) {
                $more[] = \App\Categories::whereIn('category_id',$i)->get(['category_id']);
            } else {
                $more[] = \App\Categories::where('category_parent_id',$ind)->get(['category_id']);
            }
        }
        return $more;
    }
```

Now it works

My next challenge is to find how to merge this 2 arrays :)